# QT QtreeView show image when tree is expanded and collapsed

Tags: qt

I have a requirement in the TreeView where I have to show down arrow image when tree is collapsed and up arrow image when tree is expanded and this is applicable for each parent item in the tree.
My UI will have only 1 column and this arrow images i have to show at the end of the row.

I am using QTreeView and I can see expand and collapse signals.But it does have only index arguement.But I need item rectanlge details to show the image at the end of the row.Could you pls suggest is there any way to achieve this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way would be to use [QTreeView::setIndexWidget](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qabstractitemview.html#setIndexWidget) (inherited from QAbstractItemView). With this method, you can set your own widget to render the nodes.

If you have more sophisticated requirements, you need to implement a custom delegate. Please have a look at the [QAbstractItemDelegate Class Reference](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qabstractitemdelegate.html) and [Designing Delegates](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/qq/qq24-delegates.html). By the use of delegates, you have complete rendering control over your items.

Comment: Hi ..thanks for the response .I think I can use the what  is suggested in designing delegates..